# How to get nicely formatted comment count and date for a blog post in subtext

Tags: asp.net, skin, subtext

I'm creating my own skin for subtext, and there's one thing I can't figure out... How can I get the post date (with permalink) and comment count link to the posts comments formatted how I want?

In the base skin, there's this:

```
<asp:literal id="PostDesc" runat="server" />
```

That generates something like this: `posted @ Thursday, July 29, 2010 2:13 AM | Feedback (0)`

How do I get this to look like something Phill Haack has on his site (http://haacked.com)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out after excruciating hours of research, trial and error, and browsing subtext source code.

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%#string.Format("{0}#feedback", Url.EntryUrl((IEntryIdentity)Container.DataItem)) %>'>View comments (<%#Eval("FeedBackCount") %>)</asp:HyperLink>
```

For comment count, and I will do something similar with date.